# USB umounting on ubuntu

Tags: usb, configuration, unmount

When writing 6GB the unmount takes forever.

Currently I watch the Writebacks with this command

```
watch grep -e Dirty: -e Writeback: /proc/meminfo
```

What would be the ideal way to avoid having to do this.

I.E. what parameters do I use to set these values

```
 evm.dirty_background_bytes=
 vm.dirty_background_ratio=
 vm.dirty_bytes=
 vm.dirty_ratio=
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With e.g. uSD cards (flash-memory) it is "normal" to have huge amounts of data buffered (in RAM often) as the write "ends".

As you unmount, this buffered data will be written (buffer flush) to the media,
this flush is what you have to wait for.